# Split specific column(s)

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I have this kind of recrods:

```
1 2 12345
2 4 98231
...
```

I need to split the third column into sub-columns to get this (separated by single-space for example):

```
1 2 1 2 3 4 5
2 4 9 8 2 3 1
```

Can anybody offer me a nice solution in sed, awk, ... etc ? Thanks!

EDIT: the size of the original third column may vary record by record.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Awk

```
% echo '1 2 12345
2 4 98231
...' | awk '{
    gsub(/./, "& ", $3)
    print
}
'
1 2 1 2 3 4 5
2 4 9 8 2 3 1
...
```

[Tested with GNU Awk 3.1.7]

This takes every character (`/./`) in the third column (`$3`) and replaces (`gsub()`) it with itself followed by a space (`"& "`) before printing the entire line.

Comment: @user1116360: You're welcome. I notice that you've asked a few sed and awk questions recently and would recommend having a read of the [sed & awk book](http://tinyurl.com/SedAwkBook) so that you can have a go at writing some of these scripts yourself. I also suggest that you register as a user and give yourself a meaningful name (see: ["Making a good impression" in Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) for the reason why).

Answer (score 3):

Sed solution:

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9]\)/\1 /g' -e 's/ \+/ /g'
```

The first sed expression replaces every digit with the same digit followed by a space. The second expression replaces every block of spaces with a single space, thus handling the double spaces introduced by the previous expression. With non-GNU seds you may need to use two sed invocations (one for each `-e`).

Comment: @Ismael: nice! I didn't know about `&`.

Comment: @Eduardo: you're welcome. BTW, you may want to take a look at the original UNIX regular expressions in the [ed manpage](http://man.cat-v.org/unix_8th/1/ed).

Answer (score 2):

#### Using perl:

```
perl -pe 's/([0-9])(?! )/\1 /g' INPUT_FILE
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat tmp
1 2 12345
2 4 98231
[jaypal:~/Temp] perl -pe 's/([0-9])(?! )/\1 /g' tmp
1 2 1 2 3 4 5 
2 4 9 8 2 3 1
```

#### Using gnu sed:

```
sed 's/\d/& /3g' INPUT_FILE
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] sed 's/[0-9]/& /3g' tmp
1 2 1 2 3 4 5 
2 4 9 8 2 3 1
```

#### Using gnu awk:

```
gawk '{print $1,$2,gensub(/./,"& ","G", $NF)}' INPUT_FILE
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] gawk '{print $1,$2,gensub(/./,"& ","G", $NF)}' tmp
1 2 1 2 3 4 5 
2 4 9 8 2 3 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk substr and printf:

```
[srikanth@myhost ~]$ cat records.log 
1 2 12345 6 7
2 4 98231 8 0

[srikanth@myhost ~]$ awk '{ len=length($3); for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if(i==3) { for(j = 1; j <= len; j++){ printf substr($3,j,1) " "; } } else { printf $i " "; } } printf("\n"); }' records.log 
1 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
2 4 9 8 2 3 1 8 0
```

You can use this for more than three column records as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about spaces, this is a succinct version:

```
sed 's/[0-9]/& /g'
```

but if you need to remove spaces, we just chain another regexp:

```
sed 's/[0-9]/& /g;s/   */ /g'
```

Note this is compatible with the original `sed`, thus will run on any UNIX-like.

Comment: Why not do `sed 's/[0-9]/& /3g'` instead of nesting to another substitution.

Comment: @JaypalSingh because combining `g` with a number gives an unpredictable result (i.e. implementation defined), and also many old implementations don't support the number flag.

Comment: Aah you are right, it might not work with `bsd sed` may be only `gnu sed`. Sorry about that.

Comment: However, it's otherwise a fine suggestion :).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F '' '$1=$1' data.txt | tr -s ' '
1 2 1 2 3 4 5
2 4 9 8 2 3 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo -e "1 2 12345\n2 4 98231" | sed 's/\B\s*/ /g'
1 2 1 2 3 4 5
2 4 9 8 2 3 1
```

Most probably GNU sed only.